Is there an automatic way of logging in spring boot
I had a wild idea, if there would be a way we can automatically log before and after while doing a repository layer function. Like before update the entity was like this and after update entity is like this. I would want some generic for all repository classes in my application and not write explicitly for every repository class. Is this possible in spring boot ?

What you are asking for is called data auditing. Spring Data Envers will log all Spring Data changes to your database. It will also aggregate all changes that were made in a given transaction and hooks to capture which user made the changes. Envers will create 'sister' tables to your database that mirror each @Entity and will add columns to the sister table that indicate whether a given field was modified during the transaction. A couple of 'overhead' tables are added to manage the aggregations. There are some limitations: @Modifying queries, batch updates, and native modifying queries are not audited by Envers.

Correction it is not Spring Data Envers that will log all changes, rather Hibernate Envers. Spring Data Envers is nothing more then a wrapper to make it easier to query the Hibernate Envers data.
